# How do I detect what template is being used?

Tags: magento

I need to detect that I am on the onestepcheckout page. I am currently using:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/onestepcheckout/"){
```

But I am wondering if I can get the info from a Magento object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the controller name in the IF condition.

```
if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() != 'onestepcheckout') {
```

Similarly, you can also get action name, module name, etc.

Have a look at this article:- [Magento: How to get controller, module, action and router name?](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-controller-action-and-module-name-in-template-file/)

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$currentUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();`

The method being called in Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php

```
    /**
     * Retrieve current url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentUrl()
    {
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        $url = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getServer('REQUEST_URI');
        return $url;
//        return $this->_getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true));
    }
```

Since the above may return a more full URL and not the URI you could use:

`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();`

and get the action name of the controller action being called.